# Magento 2.4.3 upgrade error

Tags: error, upgrade, magento2.4

I just upgraded from Magento 2.3.6 to 2.4.3 near the end of the installation I received this error:

[image]

Does anyone know why I get this error? What does it mean?

We do have MSI disabled in case that has

[image: This is the error I get when I use PHP 7.4]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the upgrade requires a function "str_contains()" that only exists in PHP8.
Can you try with php8 instead of 7.4 ?

Comment: I actually run PHP 7.3 when if change it to any higher I get a new error message. updated my OP

Comment: a simple composer require / update is not sufficient to go from 2.3.6 to 2.4.3
There are many modifications that need to be done "manually". Did you set up elasticsearch ?

Comment: ES is set up and it is also the correct Version that supports 2.4.3